# Laravel 4.2 and smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, smtp, gmail

I have a problem with sending an email with google SMTP using laravel 4.2

This is the mail.php file

```
return array(
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'from' => array('address' => 'mymail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Auth'),
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
    // 'username' => 'mymail',
    'password' => 'mypass',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false
);
```

and this is the controller code

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
     public function home(){
          Mail::send('emails.auth.test', array('name' => 'Auth'), function($message){
                $message->to('mail@gmail.com', 'Name Name')->subject('Test Email');
          });
          return View::make('home');
     }
}
```

and this is the view file

```
Hello {{ $name }}!
```

in php.ini file

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

and I have enabled Access for less secure apps from https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

After that, I have this error
**Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]**

Comment: Have you done this? https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha Go there, follow the steps and then try to send the email again from your script. Not sure if that will help or not, but I've run into that problem before and had to do that to get email to work.

Comment: I do that and the problem still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls change  this in your mail.php

1) from  'encryption' => 'ssl' to 'encryption' => 'tls'

2)  from 'driver' => 'smtp', to 'driver' => 'sendmail'

its work for me... All the best

Comment: I think this is changing the intended approach and the way the OP wanted to access gmail.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make some changes in your Gmail settings. Login to your Google account and click on My Account. Once you are on My Account page then click on Sign-in & Security.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change 'port' => 587, in mail.php